# Python lists with scandinavic letters

Tags: python, list, encoding

Can anyone explain what causes this for better understanding of the environment?

emacs, unix

input:

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
    for files in f:
        print files
        split = files.split()
        print split
```

output:

```
Hello world
['Hello', 'world']
Hello wörld
['Hello', 'w\xf6rld']
```

Comment: what encoding are you using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python is printing the string representation, which includes a non-printable byte. Non-printable bytes (anything outside the ASCII range or a control character) is displayed as an escape sequence.

The point is that you can copy that representation and paste it into Python code or into the interpreter, producing the exact same value.

The `\xf6` escape code represents a byte with hex value F6, which when interpreted as a Latin-1 byte value, is the `ö` character.

You probably want to decode that value to Unicode to handle the data consistently. If you don't yet know what Unicode really is, or want to know anything else about encodings, see:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 2):

In python, lists are simply printed using unicode encoding. Basically printing a list makes the list calls `__repr__` on each element (which results in a unicode print for strings). If you print each element by itself (in which case a strings `__str__` method is used, rather than the list's) you get what you expect.

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as f:
    for inp in f:
        files = inp.decode('latin-1') // just to make sure this works on different systems
        print files
        split = files.split()
        print split
        print split[0]
        print split[1]
```

Output:

```
hello world

[u'hello', u'world']
hello
world
hello wörld
[u'hello', u'w\xf6rld']
hello
wörld
```

Answer (score 0):

python-mode.el

After adapting the print-forms for Python3

`py-execute-buffer-python3`

prints nicely:

Hello world

```
['Hello', 'world']
```

Hello wörld

```
['Hello', 'wörld']
```